# Is this the correct use of the `section` html5 tag?

Tags: html, markup

I've started to make the transition to html5 and have been struggled to get the concept of the section tag and where exactly it needs to be used. Have I got the right idea in the following code?

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Chris Mepham</h1>
    <section id="who">
        <h2>Who am I?</h2>
        <p>I am a freelance web designer and programmer 
        based in Sudbury, Suffolk. I create modern, bespoke 
        websites and applications for businesses in the uk at 
        affordable prices.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="what">
        <h2>What can I do?</h2>
        <p>I can create you a website and put it online! From 
        conseption through to delivering the finished website. 
        I will ensure the site has been created with strict W3C 
        compliance to ensure maximum cross-browser compatibility.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="skills">
        <h2>My Skills</h2>
        <p>List of skills.</p>
    </section>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: "conseption" is spelled conception, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct to me.

The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) says:

> The section element represents a generic document or application section. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.